# Drupal 7 migration between servers - warning "failed to open string"

Tags: php, postgresql, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to set up a development Drupal 7 site on a WAPP stack on my local PC.
Production is on a hosted LAMP stack.

- Copied tables from MySQL to Postgres
- Copied files to local file system folder
- edited database related entries in settings.php

Now on localhost I keep receiving bunch of warnings similar to below quoted:

```
Warning: include_once(C:\Bitnami\wappstack-7.1.13-0\apache2\htdocs\drupal/modules/views/theme/theme.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include_once() (line 1065 of C:\Bitnami\wappstack-7.1.13-0\apache2\htdocs\drupal\includes\theme.inc).
```

Any ideas where did I go wrong ?
TIA
Pavel

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with database(s). Basically it's telling you that a file can't be found where it's expected to be found (the first path on that error line). The file is the theme.inc of Views module which is for some reason expected to be found from the modules folder in the Drupal root. It should be located in the sites/all/modules folder (like all custom modules) so I don't know why it's being searched from the root modules folder.

Comment: Well, do you have that file there or not? Is it readable? It can be either file is missing or permissions problem.

Comment: It's located in the correct place, ie ""C:\Bitnami\wappstack-7.1.13-0\apache2\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\views""

Answer (score 0):

Found the error: I did not follow Bitname specific installation instructions

[Installing custom PHP app with Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/php/#create_custom_application_php)